# How does this Bayesian updating work $z_i=f+a_i+\epsilon_i$

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, bayesian-probability

$z_i=f+a_i+\epsilon_i$ ，where $f\sim N(\bar{f},\sigma_{f}^2)$ ; $a_i\sim N(\bar{a_{i}},\sigma_{a}^2)$; $\epsilon_i\sim N(0,\sigma_{\epsilon}^2)$. We can see the signals $\{z_i\}$ where $i\subseteq {1,2,……,M}$, and note that $f$ is a common term for all signals. The question is we want to know the **Posterior mean** of $a_i$ for any $i$.

The outcome in that paper is as follows but I don't understand it. I want a more detailed process.

\begin{array}{l}
E\left[a_{i} \mid\left\{z_{i}\right\}_{i=1, \ldots, M}\right] \\
=\bar{a}_{i}+\frac{\sigma_{a}^{2}\left(\sigma_{a}^{2}+\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}+(M-1) \sigma_{f}^{2}\right)}{\left(\sigma_{a}^{2}+\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}\right)\left(\sigma_{a}^{2}+\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}+M \sigma_{f}^{2}\right)}\left(z_{i}-\bar{z}_{i}\right)-\frac{\sigma_{a}^{2} \sigma_{f}^{2}}{\left(\sigma_{a}^{2}+\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}\right)\left(\sigma_{a}^{2}+\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}+M \sigma_{f}^{2}\right)} \sum_{j \neq i}\left(z_{j}-\bar{z}_{j}\right)
\end{array}

Comment: duplicate asked simultaneously in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4648165/bayesian-updating-z-i-fa-i-epsilon-i

Comment: Might be more appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\one}{\mathbf{1}}
\newcommand{\diag}{\textrm{diag}}
\newcommand{\Id}{\textrm{Id}}$
I guess you assume independence of the random variables $f,a,\varepsilon$, which I am going to use.

**General strategy** for Gaussian conditioning in linear models:

Let $a\sim N(\bar{a},Q_{a})$ on $\bR^{n}$ and $z = Aa+\eta$, where $A\in\bR^{m \times n}$ and $\eta \sim N(\bar{\eta},Q_{\eta})$ on $\bR^{m}$ is independent of $a$.
Then consider the joint distribution of $a$ and $z$,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ z
\end{pmatrix}
\sim
N\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
    \bar{a}\\ A\bar{a}+\bar{\eta}
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
    Q_{a} & Q_{a}A^{\top} \\ A Q_{a} & Q_{\eta} + A Q_{a} A^{\top}
\end{pmatrix}
\right)
$$
and apply the Gaussian conditioning formula (see e.g. [here, scroll down to Conditional distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)) to obtain the conditional mean
$$
(\ast)\qquad
\bar{a}^{z}
=
\bar{a} + (Q_{a}A^{\top}) (Q_{\eta} + A Q_{a} A^{\top})^{-1} (z-A\bar{a}-\bar{\eta}).
$$

**Answer to your question:**

Now let us consider your particular case and denote $\one_{m} = (1,\dots,1)^{\top} \in \bR^{m}$ and a diagonal matrix with the values $s_{1},\dots,s_{m}$ on the diagonal by $\diag(s_{1},\dots,s_{m})$ and by $\diag(s)$ if all $s_{j}$ equal $s$.

The first nontrivial step is to identify $\eta$ correctly: $z = A a + \eta$, where $A = \mathrm{Id_{M}}$ and
$$
\eta
=
\underbrace{(\one \ \Id_{M})}_{=: B} \begin{pmatrix}
    f\\
    \varepsilon_{1}\\
    \vdots\\
    \varepsilon_{M}
\end{pmatrix}
\sim
N\left(
\bar{f}\one , B \, \diag(\sigma_{f}^2,\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2},\dots,\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}) \, B^{\top}
\right).
$$
(Here we used the fact that $y = Bx$, $x\sim N(\bar{x},Q_{x})$ implies $y\sim N(B\bar{x},BQ_{x}B^{\top})$; I can provide details on this if required.)
Then, a simple (but tedious) computation shows that
\begin{align*}
Q_{\eta} + AQ_{a}A^{\top}
&=
\diag(\sigma_{a}^{2} + \sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}) + \sigma_{f}^{2} \one \one^{\top},
\\
(Q_{\eta} + AQ_{a}A^{\top})^{-1}
&=
\frac{\diag(\sigma_{a}^{2} + \sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2} + M \sigma_{f}^{2}) - \sigma_{f}^{2} \one \one^{\top}}{(\sigma_{a}^{2} + \sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2})(\sigma_{a}^{2} + \sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2} + M \sigma_{f}^{2})}
\end{align*}
Note that finding the inverse might be hard, but showing that its the inverse, once you have it, is easy (but tedious): Simply multiply the two matrices above to obtain $\Id_{M}$.

If you plug this into $(\ast)$ and write it out componentwise you obtain the desired result.

Hope this helps. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask in the comments.

**Remarks:**

- $(\ast)$ holds similarly if $\bR^{m}$ and $\bR^{n}$ are replaced by arbitrary separable Hilbert space (possibly infinite-dimensional). In this case replace "transpose" $A^{\top}$ by "adjoint" $A^{\ast}$.
- There is also a formula for the conditional covariance matrix/covariance operator, which, somewhat surprisingly, does not dependent of $z$ (a particular property of Gaussian conditioning):
  $$
  Q_{a}^{z}
  =
  Q_{a} - Q_{a}A^{\top} (Q_{\eta} + AQ_{a}A^{\top})^{-1} A Q_{a}.
  $$
  $a|z \sim N(\bar{a}^{z},Q_{a}^{z})$ has again a normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's really helpful, and it's broadly applicable.